# CKFinder - The uploaded file is corrupt

Tags: ckfinder

I am trying to use CKFinder in my .NET application.  I cannot get any uploads to work, no matter how big or small the file is, or what type of file it is.  I have given everyone entire control over the folder that CKFinder should be uploading to (for testing purposes), and it still doesn't work.  It is always giving me a "The uploaded file is corrupt" error.  Doesn't matter if I try to run it local on my Windows 7 machine, or if I push live on a Windows Server 2012 R2 machine.  Please someone help...there is no documentation about this, or I cannot find anything that is relevant to this situation.  Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is possible [Friendly URLs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj891072.aspx) are responsible for your issue.

If you are using WebForms on .NET Framework 4 (or newer) make sure requests to CKFinder are not modified by [WebFormsFriendlyUrlResolver](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.aspnet.friendlyurls.resolvers.webformsfriendlyurlresolver.aspx).

You can do this by disabling friendly URLs altogether or by adding your own implementation of `WebFormsFriendlyUrlResolver` to `EnableFriendlyUrls` method (usually done in `RouteConfig` class).

A custom implementation of `WebFormsFriendlyUrlResolver` may look like this:

```cs
public class CKFinderWebFormsFriendlyUrlResolver : WebFormsFriendlyUrlResolver
{
    public override string ConvertToFriendlyUrl(string path)
    {
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(path) && path.ToLower().Contains("/editor/ckfinder"))
        {
            return path;
        }

        return base.ConvertToFriendlyUrl(path);
    }
}
```

Comment: I have set this up, but I don't understand how to call it from my RegisterRoutes method.  I originally had routes.EnableFriendlyUrls(settings).  Can you help with this?  I am using VB.NET.  I can't figure out the VB equivalent of this:   routes.EnableFriendlyUrls(settings, new Microsoft.AspNet.FriendlyUrls.Resolvers.IFriendlyUrlResolver[] { new MyWebFormsFriendlyUrlResolver() });

Answer (score 4):

Figured it out in VB.NET.  Here is the code.  Hoping it helps someone else someday!

```
    Public Class MyWebFormsFriendlyUrlResolver
    Inherits WebFormsFriendlyUrlResolver

    Public Sub New()

        MyBase.New()

    End Sub

    Public Overrides Function ConvertToFriendlyUrl(path As String) As String

        If Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(path) And path.ToLower.Contains("/ckfinder") Then

            Return path

        End If

        Return MyBase.ConvertToFriendlyUrl(path)

    End Function

End Class

Public Class RouteConfig

    Public Shared Sub RegisterRoutes(routes As RouteCollection)

        routes.MapPageRoute("P", "P", "~/P.aspx")            

        Dim settings As FriendlyUrlSettings = New FriendlyUrlSettings()
        settings.AutoRedirectMode = RedirectMode.Permanent

        routes.EnableFriendlyUrls(settings, New Microsoft.AspNet.FriendlyUrls.Resolvers.IFriendlyUrlResolver() {New MyWebFormsFriendlyUrlResolver()})

    End Sub

End Class
```